# External file anchor click not working

Tags: jquery

I am currently developing a kind of Football Website.
I have 2 external files included on my main file. One for the ajax post data (`ajax.php`), and another with a form (`form.php`).
**PS:** All the scripts are on main file (*main.php*)

On my main file i use `<?php include 'form.php'; ?>` to call the form page.
On that `form.php` file i have a Dropdown Menu with all the countries retrieved from database.

In `main.php` (where all the scripts are) i use jQuery to get the *countryID* that user clicked, then i post it to my ajax file so it can return all the teams from a specific country.

**Ajax file return:**
`<li><a href='#' rel='$row->id' class='res1' id='$row->name' name='res1'> $row->name &nbsp;</a></li>`

And then i append it to another Dropdown menu on `form.php`.

The problem is when i try to know which team user clicked (to show image team at bottom) it does not recognize it. I already tried `$(document).ready(function(){ ... }` but it still does not work.

I use this code to get the click:

```
$(".res1").click(function(ev){
      var rel = $(this).prop('rel');
      var name = $(this).prop('id');
      $.ajax(
        {
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: { 
        subid: rel,
        postName: 'res1'
        },
        success: function (result) {    
          $('#imageE1').empty();
          $('#imageE1').append('<h1>IMAGE</h1>');
        }
});
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

I think the problem is that all the script are on my `main.php` file, and it can't reach the `form.php` dropdown when `ajax.php` returns the list. But when i move the scripts to `form.php` file they simply stop working.

Comment: are the res1 elements loaded dynamically - ie do they start on your page or are they ajaxed in?

Comment: Hey Pete! Yes they are dynamically loaded on ajax.php file when countries are posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following: Because ajax content not related to the normal onclick.

```
$(".res1").click(function(ev){
```

into

```
$(document).on("click",".res1",function(ev){
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It worked!

Comment: @Bruno Welcome :-)